# Comet and NIO - Client disconnect

Tags: java, servlets, client, comet, nio

I've this class:

```
public class CometServlet extends HttpServlet implements CometProcessor{
private static final Integer TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;

@Override
public void event(final CometEvent event) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = event.getHttpServletRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = event.getHttpServletResponse();
    if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) {
        request.setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.comet.timeout", TIMEOUT);
        System.out.println("Begin for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
    } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.ERROR) {
        System.out.println("Error for sessions: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        if(event.getEventSubType() == EventSubType.TIMEOUT) {
            System.out.println("timeout for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        }
        else if(event.getEventSubType() == EventSubType.IOEXCEPTION) {
            System.out.println("ioexception for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        }
        else if(event.getEventSubType() == EventSubType.CLIENT_DISCONNECT) {
            System.out.println("client disconnect for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        }
        response.getWriter().close();
        event.close();
    } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.END) {
        System.out.println("End for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        if(event.getEventSubType() == EventSubType.WEBAPP_RELOAD) {
            System.out.println("webappreload for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        }
        else if(event.getEventSubType() == EventSubType.SESSION_END) {
            System.out.println("sessionend for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
        }
        response.getWriter().close();
        event.close();
    } else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.READ) {
        InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[512];
        do {
            int n = is.read(buf); //can throw an IOException
            if (n > 0) {
                log("Read " + n + " bytes: " + new String(buf, 0, n) 
                + " for session: " + request.getSession(true).getId());
            } else if (n < 0) {
                System.out.println("error(event, request, response)");
                return;
            }
        } while (is.available() > 0);
    }
}
}
```

But I can't catch `event.getEventSubType() == EventSubType.CLIENT_DISCONNECT`.
Can you help me please?

Comment: How are you trying to trigger it?

Comment: I have a mobile java client that submit a simple get request and wait a response from the server. But I have to manage network disconnection and I can't catch this subtype event.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that CLIENT_DISCONNECT is only used a subtype of ERROR and that happens when the socket is closed from the client side.

Comment: I tried, but type error is launched only on timeout and not on client disconnection.

Comment: Yes but Timeout also indicates that connection is not closed. I think you should test what's happened to the event.getEventSubType() after the "event.close();" call.

Comment: I don't understand. I need to know only when client close socket connection so I can close session on tomcat. But this "Error" was never catched...

Comment: event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.ERROR, this statement was called only for timeout and not in CLIENT_DISCONNECT event type.

Comment: Yes but maybe CLIENT_DISCONNECT is defined during the close(). I mean :
- 1 : SubTypeEvent = Timeout
- 2 : event.close();
- 3 : SubTypeEvent TIMEOUT is replaced by CLIENT_DISCONNECT